# Lex - recognizing ambiguant tokens

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

All,

In my Lex file we recognize some operators as Tokens some of this operator are

```
":p" 
and 
":"
```

the problem is that any word witch starts with :p like `":presentation"` is not recognized as

```
':' word             /*grammar*/
```

and a parse error is trigged due to the returned lex value `":p"` as next Token

how can i resolve this ambiguity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead define a lexer rule to match the entire "symbol" token, i.e. something like

```
:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*    { yylval.symbol = strdup(yytext + 1); return SYMBOL; }
```

If you need to, you can do a check in this rule for `:p` and special-case it, e.g.:

```
:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*    {
    if (strcmp(yytext, ":p") == 0) {
        return OP_P;
    }

    yylval.symbol = strdup(yytext + 1);
    return SYMBOL;
}
```

Comment: Yes in fact i already done this and i return as i wrote in my question the toke WORD(SYMBOL in your example) the problem is that i have TOW rules in LEX and ":p" can be validated by both of them

Comment: My suggestion is that you remove the shorter rule, and add a check *in* the longer one. I'll revise my answer, one second.

Comment: Nice approach i should test it